# django two selection option relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have this two selected option in my html,

for example: if the student selected the **Incoming Grade 11 from public**

the selected of the Education level show grade 11

and if the student selected the **Incoming Grade 12 from public**

the selected of the Education level show grade 11

```
<select name="studenttype" id="studenttype">
    <option >- Student Type -</option>
    {% for student_type in cat  %}
        <option value="{{student_type.id}}" name="studenttype" style="text-transform: capitalize; border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px ; width: auto;"  class="slide-in-bottom">{{student_type.Student_types}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="gradelevel" id="gradelevel">
     <option  class="slide-in-bottom" class="tracking-in-expand">-- Education Level --</option>
     {% for ylvl in edulevel %}
     <option value="{{ylvl.id}}">{{ylvl.Description}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

[image]

is there any possible to achieve this functionality using javascript? and if yes, can you show me an example using my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#studenttype').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(value=="Incoming Grade 11 from public"){
    $("#gradelevel").val("CORRESPONDING_VALUE");   // CORRESPONDING_VALUE= value you want to set, might be grade 11
  }
});
```

When value is `select` is changed, then according to that value, you can change the value of `select` where id is `gradelevel`. You can add as much if cases as needed. This just a way to show you how it works. **CORRESPONDING_VALUE** is the value of the education level that depends upon `studenttype`.

### EDIT

Here is the simple html and jquery based code with raw data just for understanding purpose.

```js
$('#studenttype').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  if(value=="Incoming Grade 11 from public"){
    $("#gradelevel").val("grade 11");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="studenttype" id="studenttype">
    <option >Student type</option>
    <option value="Incoming Grade 11 from public">Incoming Grade 11 from public</option>
    <option value="Incoming Grade 12 from public">Incoming Grade 12 from public</option>
</select>

<select name="gradelevel" id="gradelevel">
     <option >Education level</option>
     <option value="grade 11">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="grade 12">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```